# Pause runtime controller request execution for sometime in Jmeter using If controller

Tags: if-statement, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I am using a runtime controller in Jmeter to control the request for some time:

[image: Snapshot of my app showing showing the "Runtime" input]

I want to pause the execution in the runtime controller for some time, and I am using the if controller for the same. But still No any pause in execution. Can someone please help me to correct the if controller code.

```
${__javaScript( "${Holdtime}" >= 100 && "${Holdtime}" <= 200 )}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lslDn.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your expression, it should work normally:

[image]

I can think of the following possible options:

1. You're using Java version which doesn't have [Nashorn engine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/nashorn/introduction.htm) installed therefore the condition isn't getting evaluated. Check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries. Moreover it's recommended to use [__jexl3()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) or [__groovy()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) functions for the best performance. More information: [6 Tips for JMeter If Controller Usage](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-if-controller)
2. If controller per se doesn't add any pause, you need to put i.e. [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler as a child of the If Controller and configure the desired delay in milliseconds there